# Rewrite htaccess with shared ssl

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, url-rewriting, shared

My shared ssl is: https://server.domain.com/~username/folder/product.php?products_id=123

I am using the RewriteRule in htaccess:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([0-9]+).html$ product.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}`

The problem is, the link appear: [https://server.domain.com/~username/folder/name-p-123.html](https://server.domain.com/~username/folder/product.php)
But when click appear page not found, because the ~username/folder/

Please how can i use the rewrite correct in this case ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/
It's fairly simple. Keep in mind that I'm not an expert. I was playing around with .htaccess a few days ago and the rules were not updating for client side which is my browser. The reason was that it was loading cache. I deleted the cache from firefox using `ctrl+shift+delete`, restarted `httpd`/`apache` and reloaded the page `ctrl+F5` ( Must be CTRL+F5 ). Voila fixed.

Comment: Thank you. But this answer does not fix my problem.